# Route precedence with attribute routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

In older MVC versions, with the AttributeRouting library, I can have multiple routes and specify a precedence, so the most appropriate is picked when generating URLs:

```
[Route("", ActionPrecedence = 1)]
[Route("city/{citySlug}", ActionPrecedence = 2)]
```

In MVC 5 there is no `ActionPrecedence` property on the attribute. How do I specify the route precedence in that case?

Answer (score 6):

Are you using release version?

In Released version MVC 5.0, you can specify `Name` and `Order` for every `Route`. The `Order` is helpful in Url generation.

`Route(template, NamedParams:[Name,Order])`

```
[Route("city/{id}",Name="CityFirst", Order=1)]
[Route("mycity/{id}", Name = "MyCityFirst", Order = 2)]
```

Refer : [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx)

---

**UPDATE: My mistake! above answer was based on the RC1 assumed to be Released version.**

In released version, there is no named attribute "Order".

**Order of attribute is calculated based on the precedence of Route Template matching.**

Comment: There is no `Order` property on `RouteAttribute`, only Name.

Comment: in the meanwhile there is one (Checked with mvc 5.2.2) -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routeattribute.order(v=vs.118).aspx